# most efficient method for combining query results

Tags: linq, entity-framework

This question is somewhat exploratory as I decided to ask for advice/suggestions prior to attempting implementation in the hopes of a more timely path to the result. I have a database that stores intraday data for commodities and equities in 1 minute formats. The rationale behind this was that if I had 1 minute bars, I could create any time series bar that I wanted(i.e., 5 min , 15 min, 60 min etc,etc)

I thought about going the route where, for example, on a 15 minute chart I would simply iterate through the whole subset of results for a given symbol, look for rows with timestamps of :01,:16,:31:46 to begin capturing the open, close, maxhigh and minlow and cumulative volume and create new datapoint from that amalgamation. The problem with that is that, for commodities especially that trade 24 hours, there is not always a bar for every minute so there COULD be a situation where there isn't a :16 bar, or a :31 bar for a given symbol. This could foul the whole sequence of getting the bars data correctly. This also eliminated the possibility of just grabbing 15 bars at a time and capturing the open, close, maxhigh and minlow and cumulative volume. (Naturally, the table contains symbol, datetime, open,high,low,close,volume)

In order for either of the above to work I would have to "fix" the database every night by checking for missing bars and copying the prior bar to create a bar for that missing row. This is not the preferred method but Ill make it happen if necessary.

I am looking for any guidance on a proper path, whether from past experience or from reading about this problem here.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the code I've come up with that works BUT it is a little slow, it takes approximately 30 seconds to create 2 months of 30 minute bars from the 1 minute data in the database table.

```
Partial Class testintracharts
Inherits Page
<WebMethod>
Public Shared Function GetBars(ByVal symbol As String, ByVal seriesInterval As Integer) As List(Of ArrayList)

    Dim barsList As New List(Of ArrayList)
    'replace with TD model
    Using ctx As New BATLEntities()

        ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = False

        'get all days for a given symbol, ordered from oldest to newest
        Dim dateList As List(Of DateTime) = GetDistinctDates(ctx, symbol, seriesInterval).ToList()

        'cache data series toa list for the given symbol
        Dim seriesList As List(Of tsintrachart) = GetSymbolSeries(ctx, symbol)

        If Not dateList Is Nothing And dateList.Any() Then
            For Each seriesDate As DateTime In dateList
                Dim curTime As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)
                Dim maxTime As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(24, 0, 0)

                'loop through the data series for the given day
                'series start at 00:01:00
                'series ends at 00:00:00 (next day)

                While curTime < maxTime
                    Dim seriesMax As TimeSpan = curTime.Add(New TimeSpan(0, seriesInterval - 1, 0))

                    'get the data chunk based on series interval
                    'special condition when seriesmax reaches 24:00:00, in TimeSpan this becomes 1.00:00:00 (SQL doesn't like this)
                    'query needs to incorporate 00:00:00 of next day as the last entry for this time series

                    Dim data As List(Of tsintrachart) = Nothing
                    If TimeSpan.Compare(seriesMax, maxTime) = 0 Then
                        Dim nextSeriesDate As DateTime = seriesDate.AddDays(1)
                        data = GetDataSeries(seriesList, seriesDate, curTime, nextSeriesDate, New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0))
                    Else
                        data = GetDataSeries(seriesList, seriesDate, curTime, seriesDate, seriesMax)
                    End If

                    If Not data Is Nothing And data.Any() Then

                        Dim lastbarnum As Integer = data.Count - 1
                        Dim intradayDatum As New ArrayList()
                        With intradayDatum
                            .Add(DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(seriesDate.Add(seriesMax))) 'date
                            .Add(data(0).Open)
                            '.Add((From d In data Where TimeSpan.Compare(d.Time, curTime) = 0 Select d.Open).FirstOrDefault()) 'open
                            .Add((From d In data Select d.High).Max()) 'high
                            .Add((From d In data Select d.Low).Min()) 'low 
                            .Add(data(lastbarnum).Close)
                            '.Add((From d In data Where TimeSpan.Compare(d.Time, seriesMax) = 0 Select d.Close).FirstOrDefault()) 'close or last sale
                            .Add((From d In data Select d.Volume).Sum()) 'volume 
                        End With
                        barsList.Add(intradayDatum)

                    End If

                    'update current series start time, move to next series chunk
                    curTime = curTime.Add(New TimeSpan(0, seriesInterval, 0))
                End While

            Next
        End If
    End Using

    Return barsList
End Function

Private Shared Function GetDataSeries(ByRef list As List(Of tsintrachart), ByVal startDate As DateTime, ByVal startSpan As TimeSpan, ByVal endDate As DateTime, ByVal endSpan As TimeSpan) As List(Of tsintrachart)
    'LINQ, where symbol/time>=startRange/time<=endRange

    Dim series = From data In list
                 Where (TimeSpan.Compare(data.Time, startSpan) >= 0 AndAlso data.Date = startDate) _
                 And (TimeSpan.Compare(data.Time, endSpan) <= 0 AndAlso data.Date = endDate)
                Select data

    Return series.ToList()
End Function

Private Shared Function GetSymbolSeries(ByRef ctx As BATLEntities, ByVal symbol As String) As List(Of tsintrachart)
    Dim series = From data In ctx.tsintracharts
                 Where (data.Symbol = symbol)
                Select data

    Return series.ToList()
End Function

Private Shared Function GetDistinctDates(ByRef ctx As BATLEntities, ByVal symbol As String, ByVal interval As Integer) As IQueryable(Of DateTime)
    Dim numDates As Integer = TakeValue(interval)
    Dim dates = (From data In ctx.tsintracharts
                Where data.Symbol = symbol
                Select data.Date
                Order By [Date]).Distinct().Take(numDates)

    Return dates
End Function
Private Shared Function TakeValue(ByVal interval As Integer) As Integer
    Select Case interval
       Case 0 To 15
            Return 1440
        Case 16 To 30
            Return 720
        Case 31 To 60
            Return 528
        Case Else
            Return 400
    End Select
End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table that holds all possible 1min points in time. Then you can `OUTER JOIN` to that table to make the server fill in any gaps. The table would be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TimePoints (
 DateTime DATETIME2(0) PRIMARY KEY
)
```

And you have to fill it will a few decades of data. To query, you would join to it:

```
SELECT *
FROM TimePoints
LEFT JOIN myOtherTable ON ...
WHERE TimePoints.DateTime >= (nowMinus15min) AND TimePoints.DateTime <= now
```

Comment: Unless Im reasding this incorrectly doesnt that just create a table of 1 minute bars based on the available timepoints in the first table? I already have a table of 1 minute bars. I need to create some timeseries of bars and capture the highs lows and cumulative volume from the 1 minute bars in between

Comment: I understand your problem is that not all securities have data for all the 1min bars, correct? But you want to query data for all 1min bars, including ones without data (and show volume = 0), correct? You can do that by joining to a table that has all 1min bars without gaps. Maybe I misunderstood, please clarify in that case.

Comment: The first priority is to create 15 minute, or whatever timeseries I request from the 1 minute data in the table. An issue that can and will arise is that there MAY not be a row of data for every minute as the data capture we are using doesnt record data when there is no trade in that 1 minute period.

Comment: so getting 15 minute data for example will be tough if a bar is missing with timestamp :16 ( the timestamp is the end time of the bar so :16 is the bar to start capturing from for the 15-30 minute bar

Comment: So did I understand correctly? I think I did. I did not infer anything new from your comments. Why doesn't this answer help you? It removes the problem that some periods have no rows.

Comment: maybe, but the issue is how to iterate over the fulldataset, get the appropriate 1 minute bars to create the 15  minute bar from, and capture the max high. minlow cumulative volume and high and close from those 15

Comment: You write that you could fix the database every night to add the missing bars. But you could also add the missing bars at query-time. That should produce identical results: the appearance that no bars are missing. Did you understand what the query from this answer does? Do you understand that it will automatically add any missing bars? Btw, this answer is as good as it will get on Stack Overflow. This is a very specific issue that will not get the interest of dozens of answers. You have to work *with* me to get to a solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40972/discussion-between-dinotom-and-usr)